# Create a textFrame with multiple paragraphs

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

From what I've been reading and experimenting by myself when you add a new textFrame it adds automatically a paragraph inside of it so you can do:

```js
const tf = myPage.textFrames.add();
const myParagraph = tf.paragraphs.item(0);
// and then format myParagraph
```

But what if I need to add multiple paragraphs?

I know I can do something like this:

```js
const tf = myPage.textFrames.add();
tf.contents = 'AAA\nBBB\nCCC'
```

But is there a better way (a more javascript like way) to add more paragraphs to a textFrame? something like (pseudo code):

```js
const tf = myPage.textFrames.add();
const myParagraphA = tf.paragraphs.add();
myParagraphA.contents = 'Content of paragraph A'
const myParagraphB = tf.paragraphs.add();
myParagraphB.contents = 'Content of paragraph B'
const myParagraphC = tf.paragraphs.add();
myParagraphC.contents = 'Content of paragraph C'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use the `join()` method:

```
var p1 = 'Content of paragraph A';
var p2 = 'Content of paragraph B';
var p3 = 'Content of paragraph C';
var tf = myPage.textFrames.add();
tf.contents = [p1,p2,p3].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if I understood you correctly, but a possible alternative would be to pass the multiple paragraphs as an object right when the text frame is created. You can also then integrate this line into a separate function for creating text frames.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.pages[0].textFrames.add({contents: "\r\r\r\r"});
```